# Как повесить обработчик событий 'click' на элемент который создается в js и взаимодействует с базой данных

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

Есть слайдер, в котором находятся карточки которые создаются в js а значения приходят с сервера. В карточках есть элемент, на который нужно повесить обработчик событий, но как только не пробовал, ничего не получается. (нужно повесить на элемент cards__input__plus).
Хотел вставить пример кода, но из-за того что данные приходят с сервера, смысла в html и css нет. Все есть в js, элементы с классами на которые хочу повесить обработчик событий тоже есть в js

```js
function cards() {
        // Используем классы для карточек 

        class MenuCard {
            constructor(src, srcSale, srcNew, srcRecommend, availability, code, text, newPrice, price, parentSelector, ...classes) {
                this.src = src;
                this.srcSale = srcSale;
                this.srcNew = srcNew;
                this.srcRecommend = srcRecommend;
                this.availability= availability;
                this.code = code;
                this.text = text;
                this.newPrice = newPrice;
                this.price = price;
                this.classes = classes; // мы не знаем сколько будет аргументов в будущем
                this.parent = document.querySelector(parentSelector); //обязательно получаем только 1 элемент
            }

            render() {
                const element = document.createElement('div'); //создаем какой-то блок
                if (this.classes.length === 0) {
                    this.element = "cards__item";
                    element.classList.add(this.element);
                        sliderTwo();
                } else {
                    this.classes.forEach(className => element.classList.add(className));
                    //мы перебираем весь массив, и присваем className каждому элементу
                } // если у нас ничего не добавляется, ты мы добавляем сами "cards__item"
                // Если же у нас есть что-то, то мы перебираем через forEach, так как у нас это массив

                element.innerHTML = `
                    <img src=${this.src} alt="" class="cards__logo">
                    <svg data-close class="cards__favorites">
                        <use xlink:href="#favorites"></use>
                    </svg>
                    <div class="cards__imgs">
                        <img src=${this.srcSale} alt="" class="cards__sale">
                        <img src=${this.srcNew} alt="" class="cards__new">
                        <img src=${this.srcRecommend} alt="" class="cards__recommend">
                    </div>
                    <div class="cards__item__info">
                        <p class="cards__availability">${this.availability}</p>
                        <p class="cards__code">${this.code}</p>
                    </div>
                    <p class="cards__item__text">${this.text}</p>
                    <div class="cards__item__info__price">
                        <p class="cards__new__price">${this.newPrice}</p>
                        <p class="cards__price">${this.price}</p>
                        <img src="img/cards/cards-5.png" alt="" class="cards__basket">
                    </div>
                    <div class="cards__form">
                        <div type="text" class="cards__input"></div>
                        <div class="cards__input__minus">
                            <img src="img/cards/minus.png" alt="" class="minus">
                        </div>
                        <p class="cards__input__text">0</p>
                        <div class="cards__input__plus">
                            <img src="img/cards/plus.png" alt="" class="plus">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="cards__btns">
                        <button class="btn btn-one">Купить в 1 клик</button>
                        <button class="btn btn-two">В корзину</button>
                    </div>
                `;
                this.parent.append(element); // добавляем в самый конец своего родителя 
            }
        }
        getResource('http://localhost:3000/cards')
            .then(data => { // data Это большой массив из db.json
                data.forEach(({src, srcSale, srcNew, srcRecommend, availability, code, text, newPrice, price}) =>{
                    new MenuCard(src, srcSale, srcNew, srcRecommend, availability, code, text, newPrice, price, '.cards__slider .cards__inner').render();
                });// Этот конструктор будет создаваться столько раз, сколько объектов внутри массива
                // который мне придет из сервера
            });

    
    }


    const getResource = async (url) => { //В функции будет какойто асинхронный код, поэтому мы написали async
        const res = await fetch(url); // тут мы пишем куда // использовали его парный оператор await, перед теми
        // операциями, которые нужно дождаться. Эти операторы всегда используются в паре!
        if(!res.ok) {
            throw new Error(`Coul not fetch ${url}, status: ${res.status}`); // Это на слуяай если будет ошибка
        }

        return await res.json(); //Дожидается работы этого промиса и только потом его возвращает
    };

    cards();

    // Price
    
    function price() {

        const plus = document.querySelectorAll('.cards__input__plus');
        
        plus.forEach(item => {
            item.addEventListener('click', () => {
                console.log('fsdfsdf');
            });
        });
            
    }

    price();
```

Comment: `yourElement.addEventListener('click', yourEventListener);`

Comment: Вот именно что так не работает. Я пробовал и просто  yourElement.addEventListener, и через forEach так как там не один элемент, а много, но смысла в этом нет, ничего не помогает

Comment: Дело даже в том, что когда я я просто хочу узнать console.log('plus'), мне показывает пустой массив, как будто там еще ничего не создано, хотя элементы на странице у меня создаются асинхронно сразу я вызываю функцию с карточками, а только потом функцию с событием

Comment: Что мешает вешать событие после создания эл-тов?

Comment: _«Вот именно что так не работает.»_ - так **работает**, и это актуальный способ добавления слушателей событий. Если не работает конкретно в твоем коде - значит конкретно твой код написан плохо, и его надо исправлять (то есть, стандартный метод `addEventListener` не виноват в индивидуальных ошибках). Сообщество может помочь в исправлении ошибок, когда в вопросе содержится [repro] - здесь такого нет (вместо минимального примера приведен большой "замусоренный" не относящимися к вопросу операциями кусок копипаста, который к тому же не воспроизводит проблему). Если исправишь вопрос, мы поможем.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
element.innerHTML = `
  ...
`;
element.querySelectorAll('.cards__input__plus').forEach(item => {
  item.addEventListener('click', () => {
    console.log('fsdfsdf');
  });
});
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

Оказалось что элементы на странице все же появлялись не асинхронно, поэтому я воспользовался setTimeout на вызов функции события и все заработало:

```
setTimeout(() => {
    price();
}, 400);
```

Comment: Это бессмысленный текст и плохое решение.

Comment: Ответа я не нашел и смог сделать только такое решение. Какое решение можете посоветовать вы?

Comment: Мы советуем навешивать обработчик события там, где создается элемент. Сейчас Вы добавляете новые обработчики всем элементам (в том числе уже существовавшим) с классом `cards__input__plus`. Посчитайте, сколько раз в консоли появляется сообщение.

Comment: Не говоря уже о том, что для задержавшегося более чем на 0.4 секунды ответа, обработчик на новый элемент не навесится.

Comment: Обработчик отлично отрабатывает, в консоле появлется 60 элементов, ровно столько, сколько и должно. И элементы с таким классом все создаются только в js. Попробовал вставить в функцию там где создается элемент, тогда появляется 60 раз по 60 элементов. если выношу за функцию, тогда без setTimeout не создается

Comment: Очень хорошо. Грабли - Ваши, ответы - наши.

Comment: Я бы хотел использовать другой, более лучше вариант, но я его не вижу, или не могу понять из того, что вы мне написали.